# Error:Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive

Tags: application-pages, session

I am getting this error in my Application Page. I have also done `EnableSessionState="true" EnableViewState="true"` in the page directive.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing it in your page directives, do the changes in your web.config file. If you don't know where it is, open iis manager, go to the app pool web site, select it and click on browse (top right of the panel), it will open the folder containing your web.config file.

Comment: can you tell me what to write in web.config file. and where should i add it

Comment: Find the enableSessionState and change it to true

Comment: I have tried to make it true... but giving Runtime Error

Comment: <pages enableSessionState="true" enableViewState="true" enableViewStateMac="true" validateRequest="false" clientIDMode="AutoID" pageParserFilterType="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPPageParserFilter, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" asyncTimeout="7">

        </pages>

Comment: can you share the error message ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `"ASP.NET Session State Manager Service"` is running.Also , try executing following command in PowerShell :

```
Enable-SPSessionStateService -DefaultProvision
```